# To-Infinitive after save, except, besides, but

Tags: grammar

a)  They desired nothing except to succeed

b)  They did nothing except cook.

1. Is To –Infinitive Verb placement governed by the presence of verb «do» only?
   And in all other cases should I view the verb after «except» which is «succeed» as Complement of the Main Predicate  «desired?
2. Does the same rule apply when I use «save», «besides», «but»?

Answer (score 1):

They did cook -> they did nothing but cook.

They wanted/desired/intended to succeed -> they wanted/desired/intended nothing but to succeed.